# Refer tag function from js?

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom

I have this code in my jsp

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">

    function myJsFunction() {
       var queryString = new QueryString();
        queryString.add('initDate', document.getElementById('${id}').value);
    }
```

And it is working. I want `document.getElementById('${id}').value` to pass throught my tag lib and I add

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="http://tags/my"%>


    <script  type="text/javascript">

    function myJsFunction() {
       var queryString = new QueryString();
        queryString.add('initDate', ${my:myTagFunc(document.getElementById('${id}').value)});
    }
```

But is slowing empty despite that `document.getElementById('${id}').value` returns a String. I can not understand why?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do, do you have a method named `function` in a custom tag library named `my`?

Comment: @Pablo sorry in my tab library there is function called my:myTagFunc

Comment: You cannot do that. as `${my:myTagFunc()}` will execute on server side and its parameter is supplied by `document.getElementById`, You should create a API and use `AJAX` call to get data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different codes. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

As commented by Satpal, you need [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/3511123).

Comment: Ooo that's why its value is "" ? How to make AJAX call for that?